# How could I open a file, read 9 seperate letters, and pass them all to another function? I struggle with arrays! (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The text document is TTT.txt ...in it is

```
X
X
X
O
-
X
O
O
-
```

I need my program to read each and then be able to pass it to a different part of it...HELP!

Comment: Why use an array?  Just use nine char vars! 8)

Answer (score 1):

```
char stuff[9];
FILE* foo = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    stuff[i] = fgetc(foo);
    fgetc(foo); // Ignore the newline
} // Now your characters are in "stuff"
```

No error handling, hardcoded file name, and uses C functions.  But it does what you want in a concise format.

Comment: @Salena, if you can't even tell if the provided solution is in C++, you may have bigger problems than we can solve here.

Comment: @Salena: if that question occurs to you, you should spend a little more time with either a textbook or an O'Reilly before posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: No, that's a very good question. This is _not_ C++, it's C. And it's much harder to get right than C++ code would. Which is why it gets a `-1` from me.

Comment: +1 from me; it's not C++, but it gives an idea on what needs to be done (opening a file, reading characters into an array) without just giving away the answer.

Comment: @dreamlax: I would have up-voted it if it spelled this out in pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to post actual code. but I'll give you a hint into the right direction.

What you need is *file streams*. You can read from a file using `std::ifstream`. It has several methods of reading. The one your looking for is probably operator `>>` reading into a `char`.

Read up on it, try to start off, and come back here when you get stuck, showing us what you have done so far and why you got stuck.